# Debezium on AWS RDS Postgres with rds.force_ssl not working well

Tags: postgresql, apache-kafka, amazon-rds, debezium

Has anyone managed to get Debezium to work over AWS RDS Postgres with rds.force_ssl turned on in the parameter group?
The connector seems to work for a bit, and then we begin to receive errors like Database connection failed when writing to copy and Exception thrown while calling task.commit().
I have scoured the web searching for this issue, and I see many people encountered it, and many Jira issues opened about it.
The response generally is "Check your network configuration" or "Disable your SSL".

I just can't get it to work for some reason, and obviously disabling encryption in transit is not possible in production use cases (at least in ours).

I would appreciate any kind of help or insight into how to solve this!

Comment: Can you give the exact error messages?  Also, look in the database server's log file, what does the server think happened?

Comment: I had the same issue. I worked with the Debezium folks and we were unable to come to a solution so I ended up disabling SSL.